# Pass MultipartformData to Alamofire.upload

Tags: swift3, alamofire

I've to convert a quite big project with different types of data that needs to be uploaded as multiparts. For that I've created several structs that build the needed `MultipartFormData` objects.

Some of the uploads are rather small, others are bigger. So I'm looking into using the `.upload()` method of Alamofire (v4).

That method has a closure to append parts to the `multipartFormData` object.

```
Alamofire.upload(
   multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            // do stuff here
   }
```

But I haven't found a way to pass my existing `MultipartformData` object to this method.

It should be like:

```
self.parts = MultipartformData()
...
// do stuff with self.parts
...

Alamofire.upload(
   multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData = self.parts
   }
```

But that doesn't work as I'm getting the following error message:

> parameters may not have the 'var' specifier

I'm using XCode 8.1, Alamofire 4 and Swift 3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
let image = UIImage.init(named: "myImage")
 let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.2)!

 let parameters = ["name": rname]

Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "fileset",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
    },
to:"mysite/upload.php")
{ (result) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):

        upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
            print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
        })

        upload.responseJSON { response in
             print(response.result.value)  
        }

    case .failure(let encodingError):
        print(encodingError)  
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work as MultipartformData doesn't conform to sequence. I've updated my question with a more specific description about what I want to pass.